# How can I get the data-id attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm using the jQuery *[Quicksand](https://github.com/razorjack/quicksand)* plugin. I need to get the data-id of the clicked item and pass it to a webservice.

How do I get the data-id attribute? I'm using the `.on()` method to re-bind the click event for sorted items.

```js
$("#list li").on('click', function() {
  //  ret = DetailsView.GetProject($(this).attr("#data-id"), OnComplete, OnTimeOut, OnError);
  alert($(this).attr("#data-id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list" class="grid">
  <li data-id="id-40" class="win">
    <a id="ctl00_cphBody_ListView1_ctrl0_SelectButton" class="project" href="#">
      <img src="themes/clean/images/win.jpg" class="project-image" alt="get data-id" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Notice to new visitors: JQuery's .live() method has been deprecated in favor of .on()

Comment: You should remove the # from the alert, you dont need it :-)

Comment: attr("#data-id")) is wrong. corrected: attr("data-id"));

Comment: For `select` and `option` elements use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750327/7389293

Answer (score 2020, accepted):

To get the contents of the attribute `data-id` (like in `<a data-id="123">link</a>`) you have to use

```
$(this).attr("data-id") // will return the string "123"
```

or [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

```
$(this).data("id") // will return the number 123
```

**and the part after `data-` must be lowercase, e.g. `data-idNum` will not work, but `data-idnum` will.**

Comment: This is returning 'undefined' for me.

Comment: For those who report it doesn't work, make sure your attribute contains only lower case letters. For example "data-listId" should be "data-listid". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992984/jquery-data-returns-undefined-attr-returns-integer for the reason why.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the lowercase part... After 8 years this helped me. I was making the same camel casing mistake.

Comment: There's a major difference between using these two methods. If you use .attr, then you get the latest updated value of data-id if it was updated. But using .data won't get you the latest value.

Answer (score 214):

If we want to retrieve or update these attributes using existing, native **JavaScript**, then we can do so using the getAttribute and setAttribute methods as shown below:

**Through JavaScript**

```
<div id='strawberry-plant' data-fruit='12'></div>

<script>
// 'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
var plant = document.getElementById('strawberry-plant');
var fruitCount = plant.getAttribute('data-fruit'); // fruitCount = '12'

// 'Setting' data-attributes using setAttribute
plant.setAttribute('data-fruit','7'); // Pesky birds
</script>
```

**Through jQuery**

```
// Fetching data
var fruitCount = $(this).data('fruit');
OR 
// If you updated the value, you will need to use below code to fetch new value 
// otherwise above gives the old value which is intially set.
// And also above does not work in ***Firefox***, so use below code to fetch value
var fruitCount = $(this).attr('data-fruit');

// Assigning data
$(this).attr('data-fruit','7');
```

[Read this documentation](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Comment: Due to very good [support of the dataset API](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_dataset), the JavaScript part should be considered obsolete.

Answer (score 121):

Important note. Keep in mind, that if you adjust the `data-` **attribute** dynamically via JavaScript it will *not* be reflected in the `data()` jQuery function. You have to adjust it via `data()` function as well.

```
<a data-id="123">link</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(this).data("id") // returns 123
$(this).attr("data-id", "321"); //change the attribute
$(this).data("id") // STILL returns 123!!!
$(this).data("id", "321")
$(this).data("id") // NOW we have 321
```

Comment: <a data-id="123">link</a>


$(this).attr("data-id") // returns 123
$(this).attr("data-id", "321"); //change the attribute
$(this).attr("data-id"") //  returns 321
$(this).attr("data-id"", "321")
$(this).attr("id") // NOW returns 321

Please using attr but page don't reload.

Answer (score 72):

If you are not concerned about old Internet Explorer browsers, you can also use [HTML5 dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-div" data-info="some info here" data-other-info="more info here">My Awesome Div</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector('#my-div');

myDiv.dataset.info // "some info here"
myDiv.dataset.otherInfo // "more info here"
```

Demo: http://html5demos.com/dataset

Full browser support list: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset

Comment: this is the best way, i like OOPS way, not using strings l

Answer (score 33):

This piece of code will return the value of the data attributes. For example: data-id, data-time, data-name, etc.

I have shown it for the id:

```
<a href="#" id="click-demo" data-id="a1">Click</a>
```

JavaScript: Get the value of the data-id -> a1

```
$(this).data("id");
```

JQuery: This will change the data-id -> a2

```
$(this).data("id", "a2");
```

JQuery: Get the value of the data-id -> a2

```
$(this).data("id");
```

Answer (score 32):

You can also use:

```
<select id="selectVehicle">
    <option value="1" data-year="2011">Mazda</option>
    <option value="2" data-year="2015">Honda</option>
    <option value="3" data-year="2008">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="4" data-year="2005">Toyota</option>
</select>

$("#selectVehicle").change(function () {
    alert($(this).find(':selected').data("year"));
});
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ed5axgvk/1/

Comment: I was searching that thanks (Helpful)

Answer (score 15):

**HTML**

```
<span id="spanTest" data-value="50">test</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(this).data().value;
```

or

```
$("span#spanTest").data().value;
```

> ANS: 50

Answer (score 14):

Accessing the *data* attribute with its own `id` is a bit easy for me.

```
$("#Id").data("attribute");
```

```js
function myFunction(){
  alert($("#button1").data("sample-id"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="button1" data-sample-id="gotcha!" onclick="myFunction()"> Clickhere </button>
```

Answer (score 12):

I use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):

```
//Set value 7 to data-id
$.data(this, 'id', 7);

//Get value from data-id
alert( $(this).data("id") ); // => outputs 7
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var id = $(this).dataset.id
```

works for me!

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".myClass").load(function() {
  var myId = $(this).data("id");
  $('.myClass').attr('id', myId);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
this.dataset.id
```

```js
$("#list li").on('click', function() {
  alert( this.dataset.id );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list" class="grid">
  <li data-id="id-40" class="win">
    <a id="ctl00_cphBody_ListView1_ctrl0_SelectButton" class="project" href="#">
      <img src="themes/clean/images/win.jpg" class="project-image" alt="get data-id >>CLICK ME<<" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

for pure js

```
 let btn = document.querySelector('.your-btn-class');
 btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
 console.log(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
 })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are not specifying the option or selected option of dropdown or list, Here is an example for dropdown, i am assuming a data attribute data-record.

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
        let element = $("#visiabletoID");
        element.val($(this).find(':selected').data('record'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to dynamically remove and re-enable the tooltip, you can use the `dispose` and `enable` methods. See *[.tooltip('dispose')](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#tooltipdispose)*.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 introduced dataset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset, the browser compa
But for older browser you can use `getAttribute` method to get the data-* attributes.

```
const getDataAttr = (id) => {
  if(currentNode.dataset) return currentNode.dataset[id];
  return currentNode.getAttribute("data-"+id);
}
```

**The reason to use dataset** is constant lookup time, get attribute would not be a constant time lookup, it'll go through all the attributes of the html element and then return the data once it'll find the exact attribute match.

The reason to provide this answer is that nobody mentioned about the browser compatibility and lookup time with the given solution, although both of these solutions are already given by people.

Answer (score -2):

I have a span. I want to take the value of attribute *data-txt-lang*, which is used defined.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    <span class="txt-lang-btn" data-txt-lang="en">EN</span>
    alert($('.txt-lang-btn').attr('data-txt-lang'));
});
```