# jQuery data() returns undefined, attr() returns integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-attributes

I have the following code:

```
alert($embellishment.data("embellishmentId"));
alert($embellishment.attr("data-embellishmentId"));
```

The first alert returns `undefined`, whereas the second alert returns an integer, `3`.

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pdj6/)

I'm using jQuery version 1.7.2 (`data` was added with version 1.4 I believe)

Why is this? Should I be using `data()` at all if its not returning the right values?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

OK. I found the problem by interpreting [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

When you write:

```
$embellishment.data("embellishmentId");
```

it is handled by jQuery as compound attribute:

```
<div data-embellishment-id="3"></div>
```

So, to solve the problem you can use lower case in the data key otherwise it just addresses the different attribute.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div data-embellishmentid="3"></div>

// JavaScript
$embellishment.data("embellishmentid");
```

Comment: Here is the source code that does it: `var name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();` in internal function `dataAttr`. Where `rmultidash` is `rmultiDash = /([A-Z])/g;`

Comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: Guys, jQuery has done that for a long time. Take a look at CSS attributes. If you want to see a CSS style, it uses camelCase for un-quoted attributes. For example: `$('#elem').css({paddingTop: '40px'});` and `$('#elem').css({'padding-top': '40px'});`.

Comment: @Vision, If we use multiple data how it's works? eg <div data-embellishmentid="4"></div>, <div data-embellishmentid="5"></div>, <div data-embellishmentid="6"></div>

Comment: @samsam Not sure what you ask for, but assume you want an array of values. Use this approach: `$embellishment.map(function() { return $(this).data('embellishmentid'); }).get();`.