# Basic jQuery .data() call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Here is the following HTML:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
 <span id="myId" data-recipientId="2"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
var recipientId = $("#myId").data("recipientId");
```

I noticed that `recipientId` is always ***undefined***...

Comment: also similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992984/jquery-data-returns-undefined-attr-returns-integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

data attributes are lowercase.

```
$("#myId").data("recipientid")
```

It would be more correct to use this:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
 <span id="myId" data-recipient-id="2"></span>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#myId").data("recipientId")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BTtN8/1/)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was not aware of this. I'll mark your answer as accepted.