# jQuery data() returns undefined constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is the HTML and following jQuery. If I return the attr("data-conn"); it alerts the correct value but using .data("conn") it doesn't. Why?

```
<span>
    <!-- ... -->
    <a href="link.html" class="textbutton"  data-conn="text3">
        <img src="/images/image.png">
    </a>
</span>
<span style="width:610px;height:200px;float:right; background-color:#bcbcbc;font-size:15px;line-height:15px;">
    <div class="texts" id="text1">Initial Header</div>
    <span class="texts" id="text2" style="display:none;">Text for another one</span>
    <span class="texts" id="text3" style="display:none;">Content Text</span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".textbutton").click(function(){
        var link = $(this).data("conn");
        alert(link);
        $(".texts").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $("#text2").fadeIn(1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xgwBJ/

Comment: Which version of jQuery file are you using?

Comment: what browser are you using ? ( and are you using the html5 doc type? not sure if that has any effect )

Comment: I think I am using an old version of jQuery thanks for pointing that out I hadn't even thought of it

Comment: [Seems to work just fine as is to me!](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/urK5L/) using jQuery 1.6.4

Comment: Although it seems to work fine, I would change one of 2 things. Either change the `return false` to `e.preventDefault()` ***OR*** remove the `return false` and in the HTML change the `href="link.html"` to `href="javascript:void()"`. See my previously mentioned fiddle for `e.preventDefault()` example

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery data() returns undefined, attr() returns integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992984/jquery-data-returns-undefined-attr-returns-integer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you're trying works fine using the latest version of jQuery:

```
var link = $(this).data("conn");
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/urK5L/3/)

You may alternatively try like this

```
var link = $(this).attr("data-conn");
```

Comment: That works like I said, but why should it and not what I was trying?

Comment: the way he has it should work just fine. See http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: look at element dataset object may be it wasnt included.

Comment: Works fine for me with `.data()` : [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/urK5L/)

Comment: I had this same issue, and it was jquery-migrate redefining data().