# method jquery.data() sometimes uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this function:

```
function myFunction (el) {
  if(!el) return;
  //input <el> is DOM
  var $el = $(el),
      dataObject = $el.data('elementId');
  //code here
}
```

I have this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$a' of null" in line
>   `dataObject = $el.data('elementId');`

When I comment the line

```
if(!el) return;
```

the error becomes

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_a' of null"

I'm using jQuery 3.2.1

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post an example in which this occurs?

Comment: We don't see where you used $a so I don't know how can we help you...

Comment: @StupidKid that's most likely a variable within jquery.

Comment: I used Rollbar report when bug. I cannot build case like this >"<

Answer (score 0):

```js
function a(el) {
  if(!el) return;
  //input <el> is DOM
  var $el = $(el),
      dataObject = $el.data('elementid');
  //code here
  console.log(dataObject);
  console.log($el.attr('data-elementid'));
}
a(document.getElementById('two'));
a();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="two" data-elementid="a">2</div>
```

Try using attr instead of data? But by this answers:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992984/jquery-data-returns-undefined-attr-returns-integer)

if you set all to lowercase it will return data value.

Comment: hmmm I don't think set all to lowercase is solution in this problem, and I can't set all attributes in my program, Ty

Comment: I need to see your program whole code but this one part I can't know what are your problems. I just copied your code and when you run it here on my answer it returns value from requested data..

Comment: @StupidKid the problem is that $el is sometimes null, which is upstream of anything that happens with `.data`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, I think so, when I comment line `if(!el) return;` Error like this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_a' of null". When I check is_null(el), Error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$a' of null"
I think problem in jQuery but I haven't solution to fix it. because sometime error's appears

Comment: @user3739680, so, a simple enough solution would be to `var $el = $(el); if (!$el) return;` Or you could avoid jquery entirely, it's not necessary for this