# jquery show hide table rows based on data attribute and class

Tags: jquery

say I have some table rows:

```
<tr class="toplevel" data-id="3">
 ...
</tr>
<tr data-id="3">
 ...
</tr>
<tr data-id="3">
 ...
</tr>
```

So as far as I know I can hide the ones with class toplevel like:

```
$('tr.toplevel').hide();
```

and I can hide the ones with data-id=3 like:

```
$('tr').data('3').hide();
```

However what I really want to do is hide the ones with data-id=3 that DON'T have the class toplevel.

Could someone please explain to me how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use attribute selector within `[]` notation and use [:not] to exclude the ones with class `.toplevel`

```
 $('tr:not(.toplevel)[data-id="3"]').hide(); 
    ^   ^                      ^
    |   |                      |
all trs but .toplevel of which select the ones with data-id attribute value 3
```

Or

```
$('tr:not([class="toplevel"])[data-id="3"]').hide(); //Less efficient though due to explicit attribute name class
```

See **[Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

**[:not Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnxvg/)

Comment: this does not exclude those with class `toplevel`

Comment: Just added explanation and additional links in case required

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('tr:not(.toplevel)[data-id="3"]').hide();
```

**or**

```
$('tr[data-id="3"]').not('.toplevel').hide();
```

`hide` is a method that works for **jQuery objects**

`$('tr').data('3')` returns a **string** . So it will throw an error when you try to apply the  `hide` method on it.

Answer (score -2):

Try This....

```
$('tr[class!="toplevel"]').data('3').hide();
```

The Selector will get u all the tr(s) that dont have toplevel class.Then you can perform any actions on that elements

---Edited----
Try This
    $('tr[class!="toplevel"][data-id="3"]').hide();

Comment: Please refer this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute-using-jquery
May be some JQuery Conflicts for not working...