# How send PHP ID value to Jquery in moodle

Tags: php, jquery, html, moodle

I don't know pass a id value of php to jquery in moodle. Have a two files index.php and myscript.js

index.php file:

```
html_writer::tag('button','', array('id' => 'buttonCompile', 'data-url' => $urlbase));
```

myscript.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     alert($('#button').attr('id'));
```

});

i need show the value of 'data-url' in js file

pd: html_writer is a moodle function for write html code, in this case is a button tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the id of your button is `buttonCompile`, you won't be able to find any items with the id `button`. You can get the data-url of your `buttonCompile` attribute in jQuery with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     alert($('#buttonCompile').data('url')); 
     //or $('#buttonCompile').attr("data-url")
});
```

cfr. [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute-using-jquery)

If however you want to get the id of your button (and there is only one button on your page. You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     alert($('button').attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: thanks! if i need go to the url, with the .onclick event in button. how can do it?

Comment: you would want to add following code in your onclick event: `window.location.href = $('#buttonCompile').data('url');`