# Find that data-index of section element that contains specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single page application that separates its pages by `<section>` elements. Content is being outputted dynamically from the back end. How would I loop through the application using jQuery and see the data-index of a section that contains a div element of `$('.narration_audio')`.

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is when ever a user comes to the page (section) that contains that div element to show the audio player in the heading. Otherwise grey out the audio player.

Comment: `$("section").has(".narration_audio") { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: @DanielLisik  when I call $(this) in the if loop I get the whole document. I need to see what the data-index of the section is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("section").each(function() {

    var this_el = $(this);
    if (this_el.find('.narration_audio').length) {

         var the_data_index = this_el.data('index');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a similar approach seen in [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute-using-jquery) Using `$(this).attr("data-index")` or `$(this).data("index")`