# How do I get this value from either of these objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am printing out objects in two different ways in the console with these calls:

```
console.log(ui.handle)
console.log($(ui.handle))
```

console.log(ui) prints out this:

[image]

console.log($(ui.handle)) prints out like this:

[image]

There is a common "thing"value I need to get out of one of them. In the first I need data-value. Therefore I need a way of getting the 12:00 AM from it.

From the second, this "thing"/value I need to get is in more than 1 spot.
 1. Under attributes -> data-value -> it is the nodeValue, textContent, and value
 2. Under dataset -> value is 12:00 AM

I Have tried doing the following after printing out the objects, and do not get the correct value:

```
    console.log(ui.handle.attributes.getNamedItem("data-value"))
    console.log($(ui.handle).data('value'))
    console.log(ui.handle.dataset["value"])
```

Someone please understand what I am trying to get and help me.

Here Is my JS code that initializes the slider:

```
$(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1])
.customSlider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    range: false,
    ticks: true,
    values: initialValues,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $.each( initialValues, function(i, v){
            updateValue({
                value: v,
                handle: $(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1]).find('.ui-slider-handle').eq(i) 
            });
        });
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        //console.log(event)
        console.log(ui.handle)
        console.log($(ui.handle))
        console.log($(ui.handle).data('value'))
        console.log(ui.handle.dataset["value"])
        console.log(" ")
        console.log(" ")
        var curHandles = $(".pct-slider#tuesdaySlider").find('.ui-slider-handle')
        var dataValue
        $.each(curHandles, function(i, v){
            dataValue = $(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1]).find('.ui-slider-handle').eq(i).attr('data-value')
            console.log(ui.handle.dataset.value + " " + dataValue)
            if (ui.handle.dataset.value == dataValue) {
                var last = $($(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1]).customSlider('values')).last()[0]
                $(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1]).customSlider('addValue', last + 15)
                return false
            } 
        })
        console.log("HELLO " + $(ui.handle).data('value'))

    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        resize_colors(sliders[1]);
        var handleIndex = $('a', event.target).index(ui.handle),
            curr = ui.values[handleIndex],
            next = ui.values[handleIndex + 1] - 15,
            prev = ui.values[handleIndex - 1] + 15;

        if (curr > next || curr < prev) {
            return false;
        }

        updateValue(ui);
        //positionSelects();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        resize_colors(sliders[1]);
    }  
});
```

****NOTE**** the call console.log(ui.handle.dataset["value"]) in the stop function will give me 12:00 AM, but I am needing to extract this value in the start function to prevent the slide based on the value.

Comment: Are all three values always the same or do you just need the value some way?

Comment: I just need to get the value from one of the spots. If I make any of the calls mentioned in my post above, I get 3:00 AM which is the value of the ui.handle before It changes. But my calls to print the object and the values in the manner above are after the value changes. I don't understand it.

Comment: Coudl you post the js code were you are accessing the time value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(ui.handle)[0].dataset.value
```

Comment: First one doesnt work, second one gives me the value the handle was initialized with, and the third one wont work. I have multiple slider handles.  It needs to be the specific one coming through the function (on start/slide/ and stop)

Comment: Now try the second new one

Comment: If you mean the current second one, it gives me the value the handle was initialized with/ the old value.

Comment: Oh ok I understand use first one

Comment: Same thing, it gives me the value the handle was initialized with/ the old value.

Answer (score 0):

To get ui.handle attribute

```
console.log(ui.handle.attr('data-value'));
```

Comment: Im sorry, I tried this as well. Gives the following error:
 Uncaught TypeError: ui.handle.attr is not a function

Comment: have you included jquery, ie <script src=<path to jquery>>?

Comment: could you show the script code in context in the question, the html file with the libraries and then your script? What is ui.handle?

Comment: `ui.handle` is not a jquery object so `attr()` wont work on it. you should try `console.log($(ui.handle).attr('data-value'));`

Comment: Im using jquery ui slider. ui slider is the object that is passed through the functions of the api. It is a slider handle. 

@dreamweiver console.log($(ui.handle).attr('data-value')); doesnt error out but gives me the value the handle was initialized with / the old value. Im printing it out AFTER i print out the object, which clearly has a new value.

Comment: @connormoore: post that js code, need to check how your accessing

Answer (score 0):

The main why you are getting a wrong value when you try to call `$(ui.handle).attr('data-value')` is because your trying to read the value in the `start` event of the slider, which is by definition "Triggered when the user starts sliding".

**Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/**

What you can do is that, you could try to read the value in the `stop` event of the slider.

[image: jQueryUi Slider Stop Event handler]

**JS CODE:**

```
$(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1])
.customSlider({
min: 0,
max: 1440,
step: 15,
range: false,
ticks: true,
values: initialValues,
create: function (event, ui) {
    $.each( initialValues, function(i, v){
        updateValue({
            value: v,
            handle: $(".pct-slider#" + sliders[1]).find('.ui-slider-handle').eq(i) 
        });
    });
},
start: function(event, ui) {
...
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log($(ui.handle).attr('data-value'));
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my post 5 minutes ago stating this because I discovered it. But, I need to know the value its clicking on (ui) before the slide event happens. If an already existing handle is being clicked on I want to allow them to slide it, else I want to add a new handle.

Comment: are you saying every value that you encounter while sliding the slider needs to be captured ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I am having a tough time explaining.

My slider has multiple handles. When I click on a HANDLE (AKA a value that already exists as a part of my slider), I want to be able to slide it. When I click on a NON-HANDLE (AKA a value that does not exist as a part of my slider), I DONT want to slide it, I want to add a new handle.

I have ways of doing everything except getting the value I click on in the slider, in the start function (AKA before it actually moves to the slide function and slides)

Comment: if i'm not wrong you want to know the slider value before the slider is sliding on it ? which is more like predicting the slide value  and trying to add a new handle if it doesnt contain one. btw the value `12.00 am`  is the final limit value of your slider

Comment: Why is it predicting when the object im showing you above, logged out from the start function (before any sliding occurs), shows the value "12:00 AM" which is where Im clicking on my slider. (Hence, one of my slider handles is initialized at 3:00 AM, I am clicking to the left of it on 12:00 AM)

Comment: hmmm, looks like some other logical issue. could you create a jsfiddle, need to run the code and see whats the issue, just add the specific code which would simulate your issue. http://jsfiddle.net