# Bind click event and argument to div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm sure this is a pretty easy solution but for some reason I can't get a solution that works.

I have a cloned div that I need to add a click event to.  The function that I am trying to bind to each cloned div is the following:

```
function allowLike(songId){
  $('.queueTrack').off('click').on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked like');
    console.log(songId);
    $.getJSON('/user', function(data){

      var token = data.token;
      songId = songId;

      $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites/' + songId + '?oauth_token=' + token,
            type: 'PUT',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('u liked' + songId)
            }
        });
    })
  })
}
```

My problem occurs when cloning the div.  During the clone I am resseting the `id` to a new one and need to use the old `id` as the argument for the `allowLike(songId)` function.

What I've done to try and get that id is below:

```
var songId = this.id; //This is the id I need for the function
console.log(songId) // this logs correctly
var cloned = $(this).clone(); //cloning the div
cloned.attr("id", queueList.length - 1); //changing the div's id to a new one
$("<span class = 'soundHover'><div class='soundMove'><i class='moveUp fa fa-arrow-up'></i><i class='moveDown fa fa-arrow-down'></div></i><span class='deleteQueue'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></span></span>").prependTo(cloned); //add some stuff to the new cloned div
$(cloned).appendTo(".queueListDiv").addClass("animated flipInX, queueTrack").removeClass('track'); //add the cloned div to it's new location

allowLike(songId); //call the allowLike function to bind click event
```

Now, this works fine and dandy if I clone the div and then click on it.  It does everything great.  The problem occurs when I clone multiple divs in a row and then try and click on them, they are all bound with the same `songId` argument instead of each having their own.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use event delegation, for handling dynamic elements instead of adding the handler as you have done

Comment: log the cloned Id and see if these are same. I think issue is with queueList.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather first of all use an attribute to save songID named data-songid to the element, as in HTML you can have single id assigned to the element, this way you can just clone the element and put in the view easily, hope this helps, let me know if you are still not clear.

More reference about [data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute) and here you get [API](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: This worked great.  Wasn't aware of data attributes.  Thank you!!

Comment: In case anyone else sees this keep in mind that the data attribute should be in all lowercase

Comment: True, @ElliottMcNary The reason is attribute names are not case sensitive, and having uppercase lowercase will give feel like it is case sensitive, so to avoid such misconception always have attributes in lowercase