# List object ID value bind with dialog modal property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following list view

[image]

Once I click `Reject` I just configured to open a modal dialog like following

[image]

So Once I submit this modal dialog I want to submit modal values to method to save that in database table.

this is relevant model classes

```
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public AB_Product Products { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AB_Product> LProducts { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AB_Product
    {
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
        public string ReasonEn { get; set; }
        public string ReasonAr { get; set; }
    }
```

this is view page code

```
@model project_name.Models.ProductViewModel

<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var obj in Model.LProducts)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obj.ProductID)

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obj.ProductTitleEn)
            </td>

            <td>

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="CreateButton">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create")';return false;">View Product</button>
                </div>

                @if (obj.ApprovalStatus == "Pending")
                {
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="ApproveButton">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Change_Product_State","Home", new { productid = obj.ProductID, value = "Approved" },null)';return false;">Approve</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="RejectButton">
                        <button type="button" id="modal-opener" class="btn btn-danger" return false;">Reject</button>
                    </div>

                }

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="CreateButton">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create_ProductComments","Home", new { productid = obj.ProductID }, null)';return false;">Add Comments</button>
                </div>

            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>


<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Change_Product_State", "Home", new { value = "Rejected" }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ID", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
    {
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Products.ReasonEn)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Products.ReasonEn)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Products.ReasonEn)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Products.ReasonAr)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Products.ReasonAr)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Products.ReasonAr)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </p>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
</div>


@section Scripts
{

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
                 $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        function onSuccess() {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
        }
</script>

}
```

how to bind list object I click which is `ProductID` with `m.Products.ProductID`

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the `ProductID` to the modal so that it can be posted when you submit the form?

Comment: yes ,  thats it , once I submit `ProductID` is null

Comment: Will add answer shortly (you have got a lot of invalid html which also needs to be fixed)

Comment: sure I'd like to fix if you can guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obj.ProductID)` from the `foreach` loop and inside the `Ajax.BeginForm()` add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Products.ProductID)
```

so its value can be posted. Then add the value of the `ProductID` as a `data-` attribute of the button (and change the `id` to `class` - see notes below)

```
<button type="button" class="modal-opener btn btn-danger" data-id="@obj.ProductID">Reject</button>
```

and modify the script to

```
$(".modal-opener").click(function () { // use class name
    $('#Products_ProductID').val($(this).attr("data-id")); // set the value of the hidden input
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
})
```

Note that you have a lot of invalid html due to duplicate `id` attributes generated by your `foreach` loop. Use class names instead. Your html should be

```
@foreach (var obj in Model.LProducts)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obj.ProductTitleEn)</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm CreateButton"> // change
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create")';return false;">View Product</button>
            </div>
            @if (obj.ApprovalStatus == "Pending")
            {
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ApproveButton"> // change
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Change_Product_State","Home", new { productid = obj.ProductID, value = "Approved" },null)';return false;">Approve</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm RejectButton"> // change
                    <button type="button" class="modal-opener btn btn-danger" data-id="@obj.ProductID">Reject</button> // as above
                </div>
            }
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm CreateButton"> // change
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create_ProductComments","Home", new { productid = obj.ProductID }, null)';return false;">Add Comments</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: can there be two classes in `button` ? in your answer there are two classes

Comment: Oops - no there can't - will update the answer (but what is the purpose of the (previous) `id` attributes anyway?

Comment: `ProductID`  need to save these reason values in another table ,  another question , why I go with `class` click instead `ID` click ?

Comment: `$(".modal-opener").click` instead `$("#modal-opener").click` ?

Comment: Because its invalid html to have duplicate `id` attributes (and in many cases will result in any javascript/jquery that refers to the `id` to fail). And yes, it needs to be `$(".modal-opener").click(...`

Comment: okay thats better to keep it mind to refer `class` instead `id` thanks lot

Comment: if `ProductID` is `04` but once it in model I can see the value as `4` not as `04` whats the reason for this ?

Comment: Strange - when you look at the html generated for the Reject button - is it `data-id="04"` or `data-id="4"`?

Comment: I can see here `obj.ProductID = 04`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101974/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Comment: I able to get the actual value using        `$('#Products_ProductID').val($(this).attr("data-id"));` , so thanks lot

Comment: `.val($(this).attr("data-id"));` is identical to `.val($(this).data('id')` and they both return exactly the same value (but using `data()` is the correct approach). I can only assume you must have had a typo

Comment: I found that answer in [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)  here it has simmilar solution as you mentioned , which is `$('#Products_ProductID').val($(this).data("id"));` but then I cannot get the exact value, its only working with `$('#Products_ProductID').val($(this).attr("data-id"));`

Comment: Are you seriously using a version that is less than 1.4.3? (this is the 21st century) UPGRADE!