# Extract attribute from DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a code that I have

```
    <button data-id="123">
        Restore
    </button>
    function aButtonPressed(id){
        alert(id);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').on('click', function(){aButtonPressed(data-id);});
    });
```

I want the function to show in alert box string "123". How should I extract the `data-id`?

Comment: You can use `$(this).data('id')` in the button click callback.

Comment: aButtonPressed($(this).attr(data-id));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
alert($(this).data('id'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $('button').on('click', function(){aButtonPressed($(this).attr('data-id'));});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dataset` property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.onclick = function(){
      console.log(btn.dataset.id);
};
```