# How to get the value of the ul list on change with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list:

```
<ul class="country-list hide">
    <li class="country" data-dial-code="213" data-country-code="dz"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag dz"></div></div><span class="country-name">Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)</span><span class="dial-code">+213</span></li>
    <li class="country" data-dial-code="376" data-country-code="ad"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag ad"></div></div><span class="country-name">Andorra</span><span class="dial-code">+376</span></li>
    <li class="country" data-dial-code="244" data-country-code="ao"><div class="flag-box"><div class="iti-flag ao"></div></div><span class="country-name">Angola</span><span class="dial-code">+244</span></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to check which one is selected and get the data-country-code from it,
Any body have any idea on how to do it with jQuery?

Comment: Those cant be selected because its a list.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant How do you change a list?

Comment: Lists normaly don't "change" and list items normally don't get "selected". You are probably using a framework that transforms an ul to a selection? If so, we need to know how to identify the "selected" item - if we know that, we can build a jquery selector.

Comment: The only way i can fined is the selected `li` class changed to this `class="country highlight active"`

Comment: Looks like a library that customizes select look and feel, which means there would be a hidden select element associated with the list. If you can find out the custom select used, then that should help find out the select and hence the value.

Comment: How do you going to change `UL` values..?

Comment: In that case you can use: `$("li.country.highlight.active").data('country-code');` to get what you're looking for. Or simply `$(".active").data('country-code');` if the class `active` isn't used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Selected elements have two values to access.

One is "Val" and one is 'Text"

to get Value: `$('ul.country-list').val();`

to get Text:  `$('ul.country-list').text();`

You can try with this

```
$("ul.country-list option:selected").attr("data-country-code").val();
```

Comment: There is no option element in the code posted. And why would you use `.attr("data-country-code").val()` instead of `.data('country-code')` assuming the OP had a working example?

Comment: because `data-country-code` is an custom attribute he used.
we cant access it like `.data('country-code')`
if we use  `.attr()` method he can get the particular value he need every time the select changes.

Comment: Why can't you access it with `.data('country-code')`?

Comment: `.data('country-code')` is not a jQuery library defined method. You can find a error
`undefined .data(..) is not a method` error in browser console.

Comment: Um, [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is absolutely a jQuery method and made for exactly this situation

Comment: `data` is a prefix that is used to define a custom attribute as per user wish, which is introduced in HTML5 and you cannot access it as a jQuery or JavaScript method.

Comment: The method in jQuery you are referring to is used for other functionality.
It is used to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion related to "change" and ":selected" word. These work with select Tag.
But. for your query answer is this with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.country-list li').click(function(){
    var dataVal = $(this).data('dial-code');
    alert(dataVal);
   });
});
</script>
```

Hope, you have got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Others comment that their is no options to select so we need to do this by add class on current click list element and I have update some html code in your then its work.

Html:

```
<ul class="country-list hide">
<li class="country">
    <div class="flag-box">
      <div class="iti-flag dz"></div>
     </div>
     <span class="country-name" data-country-code="dz">Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)</span>
     <span class="dial-code" data-dial-code="213" >+213</span>
 </li>
<li class="country">
    <div class="flag-box">
      <div class="iti-flag ad"></div>
     </div>
     <span class="country-name" data-country-code="ad" >Andorra</span>
     <span class="dial-code"  data-dial-code="376" >+376</span>
</li>
<li class="country">
    <div class="flag-box">
      <div class="iti-flag ao"></div>
    </div>
    <span class="country-name" data-country-code="ao">Angola</span>
    <span class="dial-code" data-dial-code="244" >+244</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

[why i change data-attr position to span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Jquery:

```
$('ul.country-list li').on('click',function(){

$('ul.country-list>li').removeClass('active');

var dailCode = $(this).addClass('active').find('[data-dial-code]').attr('data-dial-code');

var dataCountryCode = $(this).find('[data-country-code]').attr('data-country-code');

alert(dailCode+' Country Code '+dataCountryCode);
});
```

Some Css:

```
ul.country-list>li {
  cursor:pointer;
}

ul.country-list li.active span {
 color: red;
}
```

And Here is [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevanuj/ah8ujm2q/)

Answer (score -1):

When you click on any li that time you just need to add a class like "active" and remove active class from other li's if any. By this you can get the value of selected li.

```
$('.active .country-name').html();
```

and

```
$('.active .dial-code').html();
```

Comment: Instead of `html` the OP wants `.data(...)` (in case this .active stuff is correct)

Comment: But i wan't a way to detect when i change the selected li?

Comment: @MohammadAL-Raoosh You need to better explain your question. The code you posted is a list and has no change or selection ability. Please expand the question, add any tags that might be missing, and create a [mcve] showing us what you've tried.