# Extract data-atribute from Current Active Tab

Tags: javascript, html

How is it possible to extract the `tabid` data-attribute from the current active tab:

HTML SAMPLE:

```
<button class="tab-page tab-active" data-tabid="Tab1">Tab1</button>
```

Comment: Can you please expand your question by explaining "`variable through class Name`".

Comment: var ActiveTab =Tab1

Comment: so  you want to select this dom element and get it as a javascript element?

Comment: Possible dupliacte of protected question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute

Comment: Judging from the title, the html code given has to be very incomplete, where is the active tab mentioned? Please take care...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vanilla Javascript:**

Docs: [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)   &  [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-active")[0].getAttribute("data-tabid"));
```

**jQuery:**

Docs: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(".tab-active").attr("data-tabid")
```

**jQuery >= 1.4.3**

Docs: [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(".tab-active").data("tabid")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** to get the element and get tabid value from [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) property.

```js
var activeTab=document.querySelector('.tab-page.tab-active').dataset['tabid'];

console.log(activeTab);
```

```html
<button class="tab-page tab-active" data-tabid="Tab1">Tab1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName("tab-active")`

```js
function myFunc() {
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName("tab-active")[0].innerHTML);
  
  }
```

```html
<button class="tab-page tab-active" data-tabid="Tab1" onclick="myFunc()">Tab1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-page tab-active")[0].getAttribute("data-tabid"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to take into consideration both classes (`tab-page` and `tab-active`), so you'd better use `document.getElementsByClassName('tab-page tab-active');`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-page tab-active');
var val = x[0].getAttribute('data-tabid');
alert(val);//or do whatever you want with val
```

```html
 <button class="tab-page tab-active" data-tabid="Tab1">Tab1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the pure javascript solutions presented, you can use jQuery's class selector as follows:

```js
$('.tab-page.tab-active').click(function(){$(this).text('Hello');});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="tab-page tab-active" data-tabid="Tab1">Tab1</button>
```