# Get input value using htmlfor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

What’s the best way to accomplish something like this:

#### html.erb

```html
<!-- inside a loop -->
    <i htmlfor="wish">
        <!-- name or icon -->
    </i>
    <input type="hidden" class="wish-cls" name="wish" value="<%= product.id %>" />
<!-- end loop -->
```

#### JavaScript

```js
$(".wish").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //var id = document.getElementsByTagName('wish-cls');
  console.log("Clicked: " + e.target.value);
});
```

If I click the input, when not hidden, I get the value but how to achieve this using `htmlfor`? Is it possible?

Comment: Please consider to use valid attribute as e.g `data-id` instead

Comment: @A.Wolff Haa! Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery attribute selector and `next()` method to do this like following.

```js
$("[data-id=wish]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var value = $(this).next(".wish-cls").val();
    console.log("Clicked: " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i data-id="wish">Click</i>
<input type="hidden" class="wish-cls" name="wish" value="1000" />
```

Comment: Hi. Would using `data-id` be shorter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute