# How to apply style to the correct tag with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add more logic to [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539500/get-input-value-using-htmlfor?) but it's not working. I have to wrap my icon around a `span` tag so I get the line height properly. I'm using google font:

**html.erb**

```
<!-- inside a loop -->
<span class="wish-flex cursor" data-id="wish">
   <i class="material-icons cursor">favorite_border</i> Add Wishlist
</span>
<input type="hidden" class="wish-cls" value="<%= product.id %>" />
```

**SCSS**

```
...

span.wish-flex{
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 10px
}

.material-icons.red { color: $hotRed; }

span .material-icons{
  margin-top: -2px
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("[data-id=wish]").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var value = $(this).next(".wish-cls").val();

  console.log("Clicked: " + value);

  /* Applying the css when clicked
  *
  * We use toggleClass instead of addClass
  * TODO: Ajax
  */
  $(this).toggleClass("red");

});
```

The code is applying the class `red` to the span. Correct but how to get it to apply the `class` to the `i` tag? If the user clicks the heart or the word (Add Wishlist), the script runs.

Maybe I could change up the `css` to get the inline style with the icon and the text and remove the `span`?

Comment: `$("i", this).toggleClass("red");`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thank you! That works great. Could you reference a link for the answer or similar? Post you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `this` inside of the event handler will point to the `span` element, But what you are trying to select is the `i` element inside of it. So you have to use either [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children) to be invoked from `$(this)` to get it.

```
$("[data-id='wish']").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).next(".wish-cls").val();
  $("i", this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

This signature `$("selector", elem)` is similar to `$(elem).find("selector")`.