# How to get php ID on third page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### edit

Trying to explain it again since my previous explanation was left unclear.

What I am trying to do is simple in theory, but I cannot make it work.
I have six pages:

1. searchnanny.js
2. superhoidja.js
3. nannyInfo.php
4. searchNanny.php
5. superhoidja.php
6. search.php

The flow should be like this is like this:

1. I query user information from database on `searchNanny.php`
2. on `searchNanny.js` I use `$.getJSON("PHP/scripts/searchNanny.php", function (data) {});` to append the list of all users to a div on page `search.php`
3. User clicks on the generated `href="superhoidja.php?superhoidja_id='+data.user_id+'"` on page `search.php` which takes them to a page called `superhoidja.php` as well should send the `data-id` to a page called `superhoidja.js` on redirect (don't know if this is possible)
4. On the page `superhoidja.php` I include the js file `superhoidja.js` which includes the following `$.getJSON("PHP/scripts/nannyInfo.php", function (data) { console.log(data);});`

Now the problem is that I never get the `data-id` on `nannyInfo.php` because of the redirect I guess. If I don't redirect, I get all the information.

I tried to use `$_GET` on superhoidja.php file and it worked fine. Then pass the ID to the `nannyInfo.php`, but that still does not work- cannot get the ID (see example below).

I would like to pass the `data-id` to the `nannyInfo.php` on `searchNanny.js` because then I don't have any JS on the `superhoidja.php` file where comes my question: How can I pass the `data-id` from `searchNanny.js` to `nannyInfo.php` and get all the data on `superhoidja.php` via `superhoidja.js`?

I hope this explanation is clearer and makes sense. If somebody knows a easier work flow then please tell me. Thanks in advance.

### List point 2 example is here:

```
    var profileCard = 
        '                   <div class="col-md-3">'+
        '                        <div class="card hovercard">'+
        '                            <div class="cardheader">'+
        '                            </div>'+
        '                            <div class="avatar">'+
        '                                '+profilePictureString+''+
        '                            </div>'+
        '                            <div class="info">'+
        '                                <div class="title">'+
        '                                    <p>'+data.userFirstName+'  '+userLastNameLetter+'.</p>'+
        '                                </div>'+
        '                                <div class="desc">'+data.description+'</div>'+
        '                            </div>'+
        '                            <div class="bottom">'+
        '                                <a class="btn btn-primary userProfile" href="superhoidja.php?superhoidja_id='+data.user_id+'"  data-id="'+data.user_id+'">'+
        '                                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Vaata'+
        '                                </a>'+
        '                            </div>'+
        '                        </div>'+
        '                    </div>';
    $("#nannySearchListing").append(profileCard);
```

### List point 3 example

Tried to send the ID like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".userProfile", function (e) {
        var superhoidja_id= $(this).data('id');
        console.log(superhoidja_id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'PHP/scripts/nannyInfo.php',
            data: "superhoidja_id=" + superhoidja_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
            }
        });
    });
```

### Superhoidja.php page example what I tried

```
//get the id from the page
$superhoidja_id = $_GET['superhoidja_id'];

 $(document).ready(function(){
        var superhoidja_id = <?php echo $superhoidja_id ?>;
        console.log(superhoidja_id);

        $.ajax({
            url: "PHP/scripts/nannyInfo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: superhoidja_id
        });
    });
```

### nannyInfo.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

require_once '../class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if (empty($_SESSION['userSession'])){
    die();
}else{

    if(isset($_POST['superhoidja_id'])){
        $superhoidja_id = $_POST['superhoidja_id'];
    }else{
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Replace `var supernanny_id= $(this).data('id');` with `var supernanny_id= $(this).attr('data-id');` in First **.JS** File.

Comment: @NanaPartykar how is this different than what I have?

Comment: Just replace and see @raqulka. You will get values here. `console.log(supernanny_id);` Check Console. Your way of calling ID is wrong. That's for sure.

Comment: And, which page is **nannyInfo.php**?

Comment: what about this for getting the data-id? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5309947/2983295

and nannyInfo.php is just an external php file where I query all the tables and echo json.

Comment: Ok. So tell me one thing is your `superna‌​nny_id` coming in console.? Have you checked it?

Comment: @NanaPartykar yes. I see the id in the console, but I am using redirect. Could you kindly see the edit please?

Comment: What PHP file you have posted is `nannyInfo.php` or `supernanny.php`? Please clear it.

Comment: @NanaPartykar that is nannyInfo.php.

Comment: You need to use $_REQUEST rather than $_POST because the variable is arriving as a name value key pair in the URL

Comment: Don't mind. I'm Confused. I'm not able to understand the flow of your code. First of all not getting from where you are passing data to which page. It's really confusing. Please elaborate your data flow with appropriate page/file name.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending param in second request. That what it should look like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'PHP/scripts/nannyInfo.php',
   data: {supernanny_id: 'put_desired_id_here'},
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json){

      //do your stuff here
   }
})
```

EDIT:
Since you have your id as param in the url, you can take it from there:

lets say, you have userProfile page with such url:

[image]

now you just get your supernanny_id from there

```
var params = location.search; //you get everything after ?
var supernanny_id = (params.length) ? params.split('?supernanny_id=')[1] : '-' //123454
```

Comment: If I use that, then how can I get the supernanny_id to the second JS file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable in your data differently if you are using POST method.

```
data: {
  supernanny_id: supernanny_id
}
```

Because your page is then redirecting (not sure why) - you need to change $_POST to $_GET / $_REQUEST as the redirect passes the info as name value key pairs in the URL.

Comment: It does if the rest of your code is correct / values set - see @Denis Matafonov example for exactly the same premise but a more complete example than mine.

Comment: If I dont redirect, with the href, then it works indeed. But I make the click, and then I am redirected to another page, where I think the JS is lost and the ID is never received. Do you have any better soltuion then?

Comment: You are asking a different question.  Can you post a new question or change the contents of your original question to reflect exactly what the problem is and we can answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried explaing it in this question, but i'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing the "onclick" event on the hypertext?

something like:

```
<a href="/path/to/page.html" onclick="ajaxfunction(par1,par2,...)"> click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So how I did it in the end and I hope this will help somebody as well.

I used localStorage for this, as this seemed the most reasonable thing to use atm.

On the page `searchNanny.js` I included this on the click:

```
$(document).on("click", ".userProfile", function (e) {
    var user_id= $(this).data('id');
    var superhoidja_id =  parseInt(user_id);
    // Put the object into storage
    localStorage.setItem('superhoidja_id', superhoidja_id);

});
```

Which will write the id to localStorage.

```
// Retrieve the object from storage
var superhoidja_id = localStorage.getItem('superhoidja_id');

var superhoidja_id_calendar = { superhoidja_id : superhoidja_id }
```

And I can use it everywhere I want. Maybe it is not the best solution, but it works for now.
Cheers