# How to get data-id attribute value in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML CODE

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>204093D-P12</td>
        <td>80443</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><span class="label label-success">Updated</span></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="204093D-P132" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" onClick="ShowModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> | <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="204093D-P132" data-target="#myModal_edit" type="button" title="Edit" onClick="ShowEdit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>| <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="204093D-P132" data-target="#myModal_details" type="button" title="Details" onClick="ShowDetails()"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>216619D-P18</td>
        <td>16009</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><span class="label label-success">Updated</span></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216619D-P918" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" onClick="ShowModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> | <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216619D-P918" data-target="#myModal_edit" type="button" title="Edit" onClick="ShowEdit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>| <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216619D-P918" data-target="#myModal_details" type="button" title="Details" onClick="ShowDetails()"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>21663P0012</td>
        <td>13116</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><span class="label label-success">Updated</span></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216693P0012" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" onClick="ShowModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> | <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216693P0012" data-target="#myModal_edit" type="button" title="Edit" onClick="ShowEdit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>| <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="216693P0012" data-target="#myModal_details" type="button" title="Details" onClick="ShowDetails()"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>217496D-P078</td>
        <td>16032</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><span class="label label-success">Updated</span></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" onClick="ShowModal()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> | <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal_edit" type="button" title="Edit" onClick="ShowEdit()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i></button>| <button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal_details" type="button" title="Details" onClick="ShowDetails()"><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And i have to tried to get data-id attribute value from using Jquery in following way

```
function ShowModal(){
      alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
}
```

but return `undefined`how to get data-id value from jquery? and i have an another doubt data-id value can hold numeric value or string value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the current element context in inline click handler like

```
<button onClick="ShowModal(this)" data-id="217496D-P078"></button>
```

Then use the passed `element` reference to get the `data-id`. You can also use [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property like `elem.dataset.id`

```
function ShowModal(elem){
    var dataId = $(elem).data("id");
    alert(dataId);
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend you use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to bind event handler's instead of ugly inline click handler.

Answer (score 3):

One of the important part of jquery is manipulate the DOM.

**DOM = Document Object Model** : Document Object Model (DOM) is a platform and language-neutral interface that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document.

It has several DOM Manipulation :

1. **Get Content**      : text(), html(), and val()
2. **Get Attributes**   : attr()

Now if u have to access a particular attribute on click of button or something else then use this :

so here is my HTML

```
<p><a href="http://www.google.com" id="test" data-id="id_12345">google.com</a></p>

<button>Click Here</button>
```

then u have to access the attributes of anchor tag like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($("#test").attr("href")); // output : http://www.google.com
    alert($("#test").attr("data-id")); // output : id_12345
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(function () {
            $(".inputs").click(function (e) {
                alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-xs btn-flat inputs" value="click"   type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Javascript`'s dataset or `JQuqery` `data` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.id, $(this).data().id, $(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="1">btn #1</button>
      <button type="button" data-id="2">btn #2</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="3">btn #1</button>
      <button type="button" data-id="4">btn #2</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="5">btn #1</button>
      <button type="button" data-id="6">btn# 2</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" data-id="7">btn #1</button>
      <button type="button" data-id="8">btn #2</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, all need to do is pass this to your function like:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-flat" data-toggle="modal" data-id="204093D-P132" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" onClick="ShowModal(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to create unique data-id in your code data-id not unique.


data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal" type="button" title="Add" 
data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal_edit" type="button" title="
data-id="217496D-P078" data-target="#myModal_details" type="button" titl

then

Try this

<button onClick="ShowModal(this)" data-id="217496D-P078"></button>


function ShowModal(elem){
    var dataId = $(elem).data("id");
    alert(dataId);
}
```