# HTML store value into div and get its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` like

```
<div class="firstclass" id="first" data-value="firstvalue">SomeThing</div>
```

Here I want to get the value in `data-value` like by doing `document.getElementById('first').value` or something like this..

How can I get this value or if there is similar approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr()` or `.getAttribute()`. That would work.

**jQuery Solution**

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('#first').attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstclass" id="first" data-value="firstvalue">SomeThing</div>
```

**JavaScript Solution**

```js
function Example(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('first').getAttribute("data-value")); 
}
Example();
```

```html
<div class="firstclass" id="first" data-value="firstvalue">SomeThing</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. Consider using it:

```
// To get/read the value
$("#first").data("value")
// To set the value
$("#first").data("value", "foo-bar")
```

Docs:

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, as set by `data(name, value)` or by an HTML5 `data-*`
>   attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it as a normal attribute and use plain javascript as follows:

```
document.getElementById("first").getAttribute('data-value');
```

Since the attribute naming follows the `data-` naming convention we can use the HTML5 data specification.

In plain javascript you use the **dataset** API:

```
document.getElementById("first").dataset.value;
```

However, jQuery provides a nice shortcut for this:

```
$("#first").data("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using .val() works nicely here

To Set:
   `$("#div").val(1);`                 // Sets value of div to 1

To Retrieve:
   `let foo = $("#div").val();`        // Retrieves "1"

Answer (score -1):

Use the getAttribute() method.

In your case -

`document.getElementById('first').getAttribute('data-value')`

Documentation can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp