# How can a Knockout binding be applied to the <html> element?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

I would like to dynamically set the font-size on the root element using a custom Knockout bindinghandler which does a calculation based on the width of the browser window.

When I tried to apply the binding, nothing seemed to happen, so I tried to apply a simple css binding:

`<html data-bind="css: { bindinghandlertest: true }">`

But the binding handler didn't seem to add the class.

Question: **Can KO bindings only be applied to `<body>` and its children?**

Note: I am initializing all bindings on the whole page by simply calling `ko.applyBindings();` once on DOM ready, with no parameters at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there some reason you don't want to use CSS media queries to do this?

Comment: Even if that were possible, this is not what this question is about. It's just what made me stumble across this issue.

Comment: It is possible. That's one of the primary use cases for media queries: applying different CSS based on the width of the browser. I know you were asking about Knockout, but offering another solution is pretty standard MO here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply bindings to a specific html element as explained [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

Specifically:

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of
>   the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example,
>   `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))`

In you case, you can them call

```
ko.applyBindings(myVM, document.documentElement);
```

by default, the DOM node is the body, as you can see from the [source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L446):

> rootNode = rootNode || window.document.body; // Make "rootNode"
>   parameter optional

Comment: So Knockout does not search the `html` element in case of parameterless `ko.applyBindings()`?

Comment: Edited my answer. Btw thanks to whoever fixed it in the first place