# Unable to fetch data information

Tags: javascript, meteor

In meteor I try to catch click event on a button.

I have :

```
events = { 'click .plat': function(event, template)
            {   
                console.log("event.target");
                console.log(event.target);
                id          = event.target['data-target'].value;
            }
         }
```

But I got an error when executed :

[image]

What seems strange to me is that the target is well logged into the console, and we see the "data-target" attribute.

Why can't I access it through [event.target['data-target']' ?

EDIT

Trying :

```
events = { 'click .plat': function(event, template)
            {   
                console.log("event.target");
                console.log(event.target);
                console.log(event.target.data);
                id          = event.target.data('target');
                console.log(id);

            }
         }
```

Getting :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.target.dataset.target`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not how HTML attributes translate into DOM node properties.

Since your attribute is a `data` attribute you can access it using `$(event.target).data('target')`. Also see [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute).

Comment: sorry, there was an error in my answer. This should work now, but Felipeptcho's answer is probably the better solution anyways.