# onClick passing value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send to my onClick function, the value of the mysql data that echo on function.

I have this function

```
<script>
function showDetails(ask) {

 <?php 
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM `registration` WHERE `registration`.`uid` = ask") or die("query not working");?>
return true;
}
</script>

//php code to send the value to showDetails() function

<?php  
     while ($user_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($userdata))    {
        $sak=$user_field['uid'];
        ?>
        <a href="edit.php?myid=<?php print $user_field['uid']; ?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;
        <a href="#" onClick="showDetails('<?php echo $sak; ?>');">Delete</a>
     <?php         
     }
?>
```

Not Passing value :(

Comment: Your javascript function does not accept any parameters...

Comment: You can use data attribute from HTML5 and retrieve that value via JQuery. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute) Example.

Comment: JavaScript executes on browser not on server. You should use ajax to execute serverside functionalities.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a parameter to your showDetails function like

```
showDetails(ask){
  alert(ask)

}
```

and remove the $ from the JS-Code. It's an PHP-Variable

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter to showDetails function

```
<script>
function showDetails(sak) {
alert(sak);
return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
function showDetails(sak) {
   var uid = sak;
   if(confirm("Are you sure delete this id "+uid)) {
      return true;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML5 attribute.
PHP:

```
<?php  
while ($user_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($userdata))  {
  $sak=$user_field['uid'];
  ?><a href="edit.php?myid=<?php print $user_field['uid']; ?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="sak-anc" data-sak="<?php echo $sak; ?>">Delete</a><?php
}
?>
```

JS: just make sure that you need to include jquery library to use JQuery function.

```
$("#sak-anc").click( function() {
        var sak = $(this).data("sak");
        alert(sak);
});
```

You can get more detail from [here](http://phppot.com/jquery/read-html5-data-attribute-via-jquery/).
Hope this help you well!