# How to find an element based on different data attributes with certain values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some div tags with diffrent data attributes, for example ,

```
<div class="sh_content" id="sh_content_3" data-price="price_1" data-capacity="capacity_1" data-debit="debit_3">
<!-- Content --->
</div>
<div class="sh_content" id="sh_content_2" data-price="price_1" data-capacity="capacity_2" data-debit="debit_2">
    <!-- Content --->
    </div>
```

Using js or jquery, how can I find the "div" tag that contains values "price_1,capacity_1,debit_2".
I searched long for it and didn't  find a convenient solution.
Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for this.

You can do this both with and without jquery.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-price="price_1][data-capacity="capacity_1"][data-debit="debit_2"]');
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var $elements = $('div[data-price="price_1][data-capacity="capacity_1"][data-debit="debit_2"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use attributes in your jQuery selector:

```
$("div[data-price=price_1][data-capacity=capacity_2][data-debit=debit_2]");
```