# How to get the id value of the div that contains certain data attributes values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the id of a "div" tag that contains certain daata attributes , 
Here's what am trying to do

```
 var $element = $("div[data-price='"+price_1+"'][data-capacity='"+capacity_1+"'][data-debit='"+debit_3+"']").data('id');
        alert('id is '+ $element);
```

And the div tag is :

```
<div class="sh_content" id="sh_content_3" data-price="price_1" data-capacity="capacity_1" data-debit="debit_3">
<!-- Content --->
</div>
<div class="sh_content" id="sh_content_2" data-price="price_1" data-capacity="capacity_2" data-debit="debit_2">
    <!-- Content --->
    </div>
```

Any ideas about what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Comment: what are the values of price_1,capacity_1,debit_3?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the problem is not with how the element is being selected, it's with how the "id" attribute is (not) being retrieved.

Comment: exact same question like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261915/how-to-find-an-element-based-on-different-data-attributes-with-certain-values)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, those are the variables that contains the data attributes values

Comment: @Pointy if other users think it is not a duplicate, they will not vote simply :) IMO it is a duplicate

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, How do I retrieve all that data attributes without duplicating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.data()` when you're trying to get the id, and that won't work. The correct API is `.prop()`:

```
var $element = $("div[data-price='"+price_1+"'][data-capacity='"+capacity_1+"'][data-debit='"+debit_3+"']")
  .prop('id');
```

Comment: @AymanP. then that probably means there is no element with the requested attribute values.

Comment: ,when I do  " var $element = $("div[data-price='"+price_+"'][data-capacity='"+capacity_+"'][data-debit='"+debit_+"']").addClass('example');" 
It works, but when retrieving the id , it doesn't

Comment: @AymanP. it's not possible for me to help without seeing more of your **actual** code. Try setting up a CodePen or jsfiddle.

Comment: I was using some different data attributes value, .prop() workedfine , thank youu – Ayman P. just now   edit