# how to get and set data variable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive

my image has `data-web-src`, `data-tablet-src` and `data-mobil-src` if my img tag has `.lazy_res` class instead of `.lazyload` then set value of `data-web-src` to `src` on web, but if screen (or device) is tablet than set `data-tablet-src` value's to `src` I want to do this for all images on my web page but I can’t find a solution here you are my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function noLazyImages(e) {
    var getWebSrc = $(e).attr("data-web-src");
    var getTabletSrc = $(e).attr("data-tablet-src");
    var getMobilSrc = $(e).attr("data-mobil-src");
    if ($(".box img").hasClass("lazy_res")) {

      if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $(e).attr("src", getWebSrc);
      } else if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(e).attr("src", getTabletSrc);
      }else if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        $(e).attr("src", getMobilSrc);
      }

    } else {
      // do nothing..
    }

  }

  noLazyImages(".box img");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/bdf1d94b64104ef2acd2ceee19882cd1.jpg" data-mobil-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/caa51ab4900448589201207e57b2630f.jpg" data-tablet-src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/4b2862a292b543139daa7805a58c17fd.jpg"/>
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Check https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5309947/3076934

Comment: eh, there's nothing wrong with using .attr to access data-* attributes. It's even more performant than using jQuery's .data for them.

Comment: Hi I haven't any problem with data attribute I just have some problem with my jquery I'm keen on and I'm a beginner on jquery how can I do what I want ?

Comment: @KevinB How is it faster to touch the DOM _every time_ than touching it once and using a JS object afterwards?

Comment: @hashchange depends on how often and how many times. .data does quite a bit in the background to figure out what each data attribute contains (is it json, a number, a boolean, etc). In this case performance isn't even a concern. My main point in that comment was that pointing to the .data documentation or similar so questions is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to loop over all of them and get and set instance specific values

Can do it using `attr(function)`

```
 function noLazyImages(e) {
   $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
     var elData = $(this).data(),
         winWidth = $(window).width();
     if (winWidth  > 960) {
       return elData['webSrc']
     } else if (winWidth  < 768 && winWidth >=480) {
       return elData['tabletSrc']
     } else if (winWidth  < 480) {
       return elData['mobilSrc']
     }
   })
 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b9hhc1d0/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks but nothing chane how can I apply for my code ?

Comment: how to apply? Switch out the function.

Comment: I understand but I guess doesn't work I tried just now :)

Comment: I try to understand function as I said before I'm new on jquery

Comment: @KevinB wierd...getting all data camel cases hyphened property names...didn't know that.

Comment: thank you so much I have couple of question it work's just when I refresh page how can  it work both resize window and width (for device) and where sall I wrote if statement for mobil ? (mobil-data-src is not work) I'm asking you to learn thank you so much

Comment: I fixed mobile ...needed to change `if()` a bit see the `&& winWidth >=480`. Can call this inside a window resize handler if you want also

Comment: hey man thank you so much I will try to now understand codes now so so thank you