# How to get a data-id attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get department's id value. I mean I need to get the `departmentID` from the element.

This function is getting the input value of elements having `departmentName` as a class.

```
this.$el.find(".departmentName").val()
```

example jSON

```
{
  "departmentID": 1,
  "departmentName": "BT"
},
```

My code from a BackboneJS view callback

```
saveEvent:function(e){
  this.$el.find(".departmentName").val(); // getting "BT"
  this.$el.find(".departmentName").attr("departmentID");//this is not working

  this.render();
},
```

template

```
<th>
    <span>{{user.department.departmentName}}</span>
    <input data-placement="top" 
           data-id="{{user.department.departmentID}}" 
           title="Boş geçilemez!" 
           class="form-control text-center departmentName" 
           type='text'
           style='display: none;' 
           value='{{user.department.departmentName}}'/>
</th>
```

Comment: `this.$el.find(".departmentID").val()` or with your update... `this.$el.find(".departmentName").attr("data-id")` ...since that's the name of the attribute.

Comment: What is the html fragment like -- its like you are finding the DOM ".departmentName" --- try this -  console.log("el", this.$el.find(".departmentName"))

Comment: Your question isn't clearer. From what markup you get attributes?

Comment: var el = this.$el.find(".departmentName");   -- then try this  console.log("el", el.data())

Comment: I would do a console.log("e", this.$el.data())   ---

Comment: Looking only your JSON it looks like right answer must be `this.$el.find(".departmentID").val();`

Comment: sorry wrong failure edited. this.$el.find("departmentName").val() this function getting value of departmentName class

Comment: what, exactly is `$el` and where does it come from?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Please don't try to mix jQuery and Angular, this will avoid a lot of headaches...

Comment: None of the two lines starting with `this.$el` actually _do_ anything. You’re (possibly) retrieving two values but you’re not actually _doing_ anything with them; you’re not saving them, you’re not returning them, you’re not assigning anything. You’re basically discarding both of them right away. How should they be working, then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: @Tibrogargan `$el` is a property from a Backbone view. It's just a jQuery element.

Comment: @EmileBergeron you assume it's coming from Backbone.  While that is probably a safe assumption it may not be correct (plus if you're going to make the assumption you should have added the tag when you edited it).  Read the rest of my comment.  The code supplied is not even close to a reproducible case.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I was just informing you, but the question is definitely a duplicate and unrelated to Backbone (which is why I didn't added the tag). It's just a poor example to show without any context from OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
this.$el.find(".departmentName").data("id");
```