# this.model not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**EDITED**
I'm trying destroy or set or another function use but my error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.model.destroy is not a function
```

Looks like there are no errors on code

my code

```
define(['jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    '/resources/app/models/TravelModel.js',
    ], function ($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, Travel) {

     var addAdminPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el:$(".page"),
            model:Travel,
            events:{
                'click #editButton':'editEvent',
            },

            deleteEvent:function(){

                this.model.destroy(),
                });

            },
```

Comment: `$(this).model.destroy(),`  or `el.model.destroy(),`

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined" @AlivetoDie

Comment: `$(this).model.remove(),` or `el.model.remove(),`

Comment: similar error :( why all example on internet working but not me @AlivetoDie

Comment: The uppercase `Travel` would lead me to believe this is a model Class, not Instance. Where do you instantiate it? An *instantiated* model has the `destroy` method, but a class will not.

Comment: Also, you were correct with `this.model.destroy` assuming you assign a model instance to `this.model`

Comment: The uppercase "Travel" is correct using."Travel" is pointing correct path believe me.I added @mikeapr4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mikeapr4's assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586808/this-model-not-a-function#comment74225929_43586808) is correct.

Your `Travel` model is probably (and should be) something like this:

```
define(['Backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    return Backbone.Model({
        // ...
    });
});
```

So in your view, when your calling `this.model.destroy()`, it's equivalent to calling `Travel.destroy()` and it won't work since `Travel` is not an instance, but a constructor.

**Backbone Collection do take a model constructor for its [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model), but a Backbone View expects an instance.**

You either need to initialize the view and create a `Travel` instance.

```
// Uppercase since it's a type, not an instance.
var AddAdminPanelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".page"),
    events: {
        'click #editButton': 'editEvent',
    },

    // initialize the view with a Travel instance
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new Travel();
    },

    deleteEvent: function() {
        this.model.destroy(),
    }
});
```

Or pass a `Travel` instance as an option on the view's construction.

```
var travelInstance = new Travel();

var view = new AddAdminPanelView({
    model: travelInstance
});
```

Comment: Thanks that's work.So can i ask you something about this question?

Comment: How to i getting table data's id? i tried this.$el.find(".location").data("id") but console print "undefined"

Comment: @marshall12 the syntax looks good, so it's probably that `.location` isn't present in the view, or that it doesn't have a `data-id` attribute on the element.

Comment: <span>{{location}}</span>
        <input data-placement="top" title="Boş geçilemez!" data-id="{{travelID}}" class="form-control text-center location" type='text'
               style='display: none;' value='{{location}}'/>  i added data-id attribute then this.$el.find("data-id").val()  return undefined

Comment: @marshall12 It looks suspiciously like [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43577375/1218980)...

Comment: i looked this question.But always return 1 not my id

Comment: @marshall12 if you can't find the answer you're looking for, ask a new question.