# jquery : how to get the label that originates a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many labels and 1 input file.

```
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="1">upload Here</label>
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="2">upload Here</label>
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="3">upload Here</label>
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" style="display:hidden">
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function(e) {
// how to get the albumid data here ?
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Put a click handler on the labels, and have it associate the choice with the `input` element using `.data()`.

```js
var albumId;
$('label').click(function() {
  albumId = $(this).data("albumid");
  $('#' + this.htmlFor).data('albumid', albumId);
});

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function(e) {
  alert("Changing album " + $(this).data('albumid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="1">upload #1</label><br>
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="2">upload #2</label><br>
<label for="uploadFile" data-albumid="3">upload #3</label>
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: yes: but I was looking for a more elegant solution without creating a GLOBAL variable, using the 'e' event maybe ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing about the original click event that opened the file selector in the change event that occurs when you select something.

Comment: Note that the variable doesn't have to be global, you can wrap the whole thing in an IIFE to keep the variable local.

Comment: OK, no more global variable, I use `.data()` to store the choice with the input element.