# Laravel: Change the div with ajax and multiple controller@action

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to change the `div`'s content with `AJAX` (I don't want to reload all of the page when I click on the links), i found some documentations, but I only saw "static" solutions (they  are "hard coded" that "if you click on this bring this", but I don't want to use a 3000 row switch-case on the bottom of my project).

Someone can show me a "dynamic" solution where I only have to give the controller, action and the parameters to the on-click and the `jquery` router makes the routing without tinkering?

My example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
         <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a action="FirstExampleController@firstExamle" params="[a => 24, b => 52]">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">First Example</button>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a action="SecondExampleController@secondExamle" params="[id => 1, newValue => 42]">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Second Example</button>
                    </a>
                </li>
         </nav>
        </div
        <div id="app">
            <!-- This will be changed by the router -->
        </div>
        <footer class="container navbar">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </footer>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller Actions

```
class FirstExampleController extends Controller{

    public function firstExample(Request $request){
        $a = $request -> a;
        $b = $request -> b;

        $c = $a + $b;

        return $c;
    }
}

class SecondExampleController extends Controller{

    public function secondExample(Request $request){
        $id = $request -> id;
        $newValue = $request -> newValue;

        //database operation where the id's object's new value will be $newValue

        return $this->showItems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this way,

First of all add an `id` to each `button`  and as well as on links inside `<a>` which you can use as selector for `ajax` and use `data-*` attributes for `params` you can read more about data-attributes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

```
 $('#buttonID').click(function(e) {  // e=event
        e.preventDefault();
        var param1 = $(this).data("param1")
        var param2 = $(this).data("param2")
        // so on....
        $.ajax({
           url: "/routeNames",
           type: "GET"/"POST",
           data: { data1: param1, data2: param2 }, 
           success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);  
    }
   });
});
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to specify like this `SecondExampleController@secondExample` instead use `routes` read more about [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) and just specify the name of route or the URI of route.

**PS:** this is just a basic structure. You need to do R&D for getting best of it.

Comment: What R&D meaning? I have some views where are a lot of links/buttons. Is there any chance to include this jQuery script only once?

Comment: No, as params will vary for your different request so does the type if you want to make a script and include it you need to maintains all those cases. if you are not bound with requirements then you can use vue,react or angular js you will able to meet the need.

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it ;)