# Get access of DOM element on other function by this in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `button`

```
<button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
```

and i want to get the **data-id** value then i write the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
    });
</script>
```

Suppose I want this value, or do any functionality on this `button` from another `function` if i call `function` from this code like and I want like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
        updateValue(this);
    });

    function updateValue(this){ // it will take it as a parameter
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: you can't have a parameter called `this` - debugging 101: in your **developer** tools console, you'd see an error about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use 'this' becasue it is Javascript keyword

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
    updateValue(this);
});

function updateValue(abc){ // it will take it as a parameter
    var id = $(abc).data("id");
    console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
}
```

Now its work fine...

Answer (score 2):

Being `this` is a reserved word, change the parameter name from `this` to some other like in `updateValue(thatObj)`.

```js
$(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
  updateValue(this);
});

function updateValue(thatObj){
  var id = $(thatObj).data("id");
  console.log("id = "+id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a reserved keyword in your function definition. It should work with simply using another name in the definition.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
            updateValue(this);
        });

        function updateValue(originalObject){ // it will take it as a parameter
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
    $(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
    });



    $(".get_attr").on("click",function(){
        updateValue(this);
    });

    function updateValue(x){ // it will take it as a parameter
       var id = $(x).data("id");
        console.log("id = "+id);  //id = 5
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
```