# Change value of html input attribute on button click using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html code containing input field as below:

```
<input id="'+count+'" name="quan'+obj+'" type="button" data-quantity="1"/>
```

> Whereas, id and name of input field are dynamic as shown above because id **count** and name **obj** are dynamic. (Ranges from 1-5)

That means at certain time, the above input field could be:

```
<input id="4" name="quan2" type="button" data-quantity="1"/>
```

Now, What I want to do is to get the **data-quantity** value of input field when my **name** of input field is **quan3** OR **quan(N)** Whatever (N) would be.

> data-quantity also contains dynamic value.

```
funcation get()
{
   count=3;
   obj=2;
   // What to do here to get the value of data-quantity???????
}
```

Note: I have also tried this below but doesn't worked.

```
$(".quan" + obj).attr("data-quantity","4"); // NOT WORKED
$("#" + count).attr("data-quantity","4"); // NOT WORKED
```

Comment: Are you trying to get or set the data attribute ?  Because both of your attempts appear to be attempts at setting a value...  not getting it.

Comment: Why not getting every input but then filter the one you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: No its not duplicate. We can use $(this).data("id"); when the same field is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one.

You want to get attr value of data-quantity by selecting input with a name that ends with 1,2,3...n.

This is how it can be done.

```js
function getAttrValueFromInput (marker) {
 const attrValue = $(`input[name^='quan${marker}']`).data('quantity');
  
  return attrValue;
}

function setAttrValueFromInput (marker, value) {
$(`input[name^='quan${marker}']`).attr('data-quantity', value);
}

setAttrValueFromInput(2, 2000);


console.log(getAttrValueFromInput(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" name="quan1" type="button" data-quantity="1"/>
<input id="2" name="quan2" type="button" data-quantity="12"/>
<input id="3" name="quan3" type="button" data-quantity="90"/>
```

Comment: Please don't link to 3rd party sites to demonstrate your code as those links can die over time. Just include it in a code snippet right here.

Comment: Thanks Scott. As for jQuery, it is jQuery.

Comment: And how to change the value data-quantity? Because changing the value is also in my question.

Comment: Check the answer again

Comment: I added set function

Comment: OMG. You saved my life. I was trying to do it from 5 hours straight. Thank you soo much.

Comment: You probably want to remove the `^` from `^=` because it means *starts with* and you don't want `name^=quan1` to be able to match with `quan14`

Comment: Yes you are right. You don’t actully need that. You can go with just =

Answer (score 1):

You tried `.quan`, but the `.` indicates a class and you tried `#`, but that indicates `id`. To query for an attribute, you need `[]` as shown below. Also `^=` with an attribute query means "starts with" so you really don't need to worry about the number value unless it matters to your logic.

```js
var count = 3;
var obj = 2;

// Report the 'data-quantity' attribute value now:
console.log($("input[name^='quan']").attr("data-quantity"));

// Locate all elements that have a `name` attribute that 
// has a value that starts with 'quan' and set their 'data-quantity'
// attribute value to "4".
$("input[name^='quan']").attr("data-quantity","4"); 

// Report the 'data-quantity' attribute value now:
console.log($("input[name^='quan']").attr("data-quantity"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="4" name="quan2" type="button" data-quantity="1">
```

Comment: No, I have already explained in my question that the **name** is dynamic. I mean there could be 5 input fields with name="quan1" & name="quan2" & name="quan3" ..... name="quan4"

Comment: @kamranbhatti585 Yes, I understand that. You also said you wanted to get a reference to the input regardless of what the number was on the end of `quan` and this code does that.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Above post from another fellow answered my question rightly.