# Why cant I change the text of this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked the classes and id's to make sure they call work, and console.log everything, but my text isnt changing? Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

```
$('.clicker').click(function () {
    var currentId = '#' + $(this).parents('.parentClass').attr('id');

    $(currentId).find(".textContainer").text('changed 
    text');
});
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Have you checked to see if you're getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` after the last `}`. EDIT: Fixed in an edit.

Comment: Since we can't see the HTML you're targeting, there's no way to know if any of this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused `.data()` with `.attr()`. Use `.data("id")` or `.attr("data-id")` to get the `data-id` attribute of an element.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `$(currentId).find(".textContainer").html('changed text');` that is use .html() instead of .text()