# get attribute value .on("click")on a dynamically generated <tr> table jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, element, data-retrieval

I dynamically generated a table from a database.  I stored the data key as a data attribute.  Now I want to get it out so I can use it but I keep getting undefined.

```
var row = "<tr class= 'trainInfo' data-key='" + dataKey + "'><td data- 
key='" + dataKey + "' >"
$('.table').append(row + (childSnapshot.val().train) +
"</td><td>" + (childSnapshot.val().destination) + "</td><td>" +
(childSnapshot.val().frequency) + "</td><td>" + (nextArrival) +
"</td><td>" + (minutesAway) + "</td></tr>");

$(document).on("click", "tr.trainInfo", function addRemove() {
    var changeTrain= $(this).attr("data");
    console.log(changeTrain)
});
```

I know there have been loads of questions on this but I am really new to 
 coding and I still can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe

```
$(this).data("key");
```

it depend on jQuery version

or

```
$(this).attr("data-key");
```

in you case my code will be

```
$(document).on("click", ".trainInfo", function() {
//    var changeTrain= $(this).attr("data-key");
//    or 
      var changeTrain=$(this).data("key");
    console.log(changeTrain)
});
```

Comment: I have tried both and I get back undefined.  When I look in the elements section of the console you can see the data-key attribute is there