# jquery data-id not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just trying to get data-id of an html element by refering the previously solved issue in stackoverflow.I am exactly trying the same but getting undefined.Why is it so?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-id="123" class="a">link</a>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(() => {
   $('.a').on('click',() => {
    console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
   })
   
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute It related to your jquery version

Answer (score 1):

You are using ES6 by using `() =>` **Arrow Function** thats why not working your code. It's the specific functionality you're asking for by using `() => {}` instead of `function () { }`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('.a').on('click', function() {
      console.log($(this).data('id'));
    });

  })
</script>
```

The way to solve this particular problem is not to use this to gain access to the clicked element, but instead use `event.currentTarget`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('.a').on('click', (e) => {
      console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('id'));
    });
  })
</script>
```

I suggest you to read this [documentation Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Your created function was wrong.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
})
```

OR

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
})
```

Comment: Yah,it's working but why is it so.Both are same right?

Comment: attr is different from data

Comment: You cannot use an arrow function here because the meaning of 'this' is different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: Sorry @AndrewChart, i don't get you, what you trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Your answer is fine, but the original poster used an arrow function as the callback for on('click'). 

The reason the OP's version did not work is because, when you use an arrow function, `this` is NOT interpreted in the same way. It refers to the lexical environment in which the function was created (the link I posted explains this). When you use a traditional function declaration, `this` refers to the element upon which the event occurred - which is what is required for the OP's purposes.

Comment: Oh ok ,I can understand it now.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-id="123" class="a">link</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(() => {
            $('.a').on('click',function() {
                console.log($(this).data("id"));
            })

        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect, you have to read about `arrow function` ))