# Validate if 2 elements have same attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, attributes

In my e-commerce environment, I need a jQuery validation between 2 product attributes. Simplified it needs to check if the cart has a product which is present on the same page:

```
<! –– Cart ––>
<ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget ">
    <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item">
        <a href="/example-product/" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" data-product_id="6735" data-cart_item_key="..." ></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<! –– Product ––>
<article class="post-6735 product" data-id="6735">
    <div class="product_wrapper">
        <a href="?add-to-cart=6735" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="6735"</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

I would like to be able to check if the attribute and its value from `data-product_id` within the cart is the exact same as in `article a.button` element. My approach:

```
jQuery('.woocommerce-mini-cart .remove_from_cart_button').attr('data-product_id').each( function() {
    if( jQuery('article a.button')/*check if it is the same*/){
        // do something here
    }
});
```

As you can see the ID number `6735` is in more attributes. So perhaps a different way is also possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need help to clarify your solution it would be

```
$('.woocommerce-mini-cart .remove_from_cart_button').each( function() {
    if( $('article a.button').data('product_id') == $(this).data('product_id'){
        // do something here
    }
});
```

each iterate through collection of jquery elements.

This

```
jQuery('.woocommerce-mini-cart .remove_from_cart_button').attr('data-product_id')
```

is the single value, it would take the first element that finds and then executes attr on it.

**UPDATE**

To update all products button on site based on all products that are inside the card

```
var product_id = "";
var article = ".post-"; // class of article

$('.woocommerce-mini-cart .remove_from_cart_button').each( function() {
     product_id = $(this).data('product_id')
     article = article + product_id; // we add strings here, example .post-6225
     $(article + " .product_wrapper a").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, shouldn't it be `.data('data-product_id')` based on the HTML I have shared?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake

Comment: Okay, and 1 closing `)` is missing in the if statement. But I was wondering if you could help me further, because in the `// do something here` I'd like to refer to the specific `article a.button`, in this situation #6735. How do I do this? Because if I use `$(this)` it refers incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, second mistake.. Im on the Phone, thats why. $(this) refers to the .each, thats how you can get the element in the loop. I can see that your article has class with the number of product, So you could get element like 'var elem='. post-'+$(this).data('product_id')' that would be producing name of the class of the article. Then to get button $(element +' a.button)...

Comment: $(elem + ' a.button' ).html() or smth. Sorry its hard on Phone to write it readable

Comment: Could you give me the example if you are more comfortable with typing? The action that needs is the `a.button` needs to be disabled, so `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` Thanks!

Comment: If I Will be in front of computer I Will update answer for you but I have already provide the answer in comment. Those 2 lines represent button. You just need to place attr... In place of html()

Comment: @Demian I suspect that your main task is just to disable abilitiy to click "buy" for those products that are already in the cart. Is that right ?

Comment: Sorry for my delay, yes that's what the purpose is. Somehow, when you enable **Sold individually** in the product backend, you're still able to add it a 2nd time in the cart. So I came with this solution.

Comment: @Demian I updated the answer for you. Do you understand it ?

Comment: @Demian Of course you should convert <a href to <button> as disabled doesnt work on linka I guess

Answer (score 0):

1. To get `current_ProductId`, You just need to get from `$('article').data('id')`
2. To loop through all mini cart items, You just need `mini_cart_item`
3. As you can see, we can get data attribute value by using [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
var current_ProductId = $('article').data('id');

$('.mini_cart_item').each(function() {
   var productId_MiniCartItem = $(this).find('a').data('product_id');
   
   if(productId_MiniCartItem == current_ProductId){
        // do something here
        console.log("ProductId: " + productId_MiniCartItem + " has been ordered");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<! –– Cart ––>
<ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget ">
    <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item">
        <a href="/example-product/" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" data-product_id="6735" data-cart_item_key="..." >6735</a>
    </li>
    <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item mini_cart_item">
        <a href="/example-product/" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" data-product_id="6736" data-cart_item_key="..." >6736</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<! –– Product ––>
<article class="post-6735 product" data-id="6735">
    <div class="product_wrapper">
        <a href="?add-to-cart=6735" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="6735"</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing. 2 sidenotes; the `.data('id)` and `.data('product_id')` are both non existing in my HTML sample. The attributes are different.

Comment: From your HTML, It equals to `data-id="6735"`. So it works fine. Please check my code & result.

Comment: Sorry, but data-id is the attribute. So it should be `.data('data-id')` and `.data('data-product_id')`. The attribute `id` is a an id-attribute, which is not the case here.

Comment: No, You can get data value via 2 ways. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309947/9071943