# Cannot get value of text field that is set by another function using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am setting the value of the text field using this function:

```js
var end_limit = 'data';
jQuery(document).on('change', 'select[name=txtSetValue]', function() {
  jQuery("input[name=time]").prop('disabled', false);
  jQuery('input[name=time]').data('endtime', end_limit);
});

jQuery(document).on('change', '.get_value', function() {
  console.log(jQuery("input[name=time]").data('endtime'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="time" value="" id="time" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" requried="1" data-endtime="" disabled="disabled">

<select name="txtSetValue">
<option value="0">One</option>
<option value="1">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Get Value" class="get_value"/>
```

Now when I change the select field I can see the data is attached to endtime attribute in the browser but when i try to get it through this script then endLimit does not contains any value, but in another place same function is working there the value is not dynamic set.

```
jQuery(document).on('change',".get_value",function(){
    var endLimit =  jQuery(this).attr('data-endtime');'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last block of code you're referencing the input element by `.timepicker`, but the `timepicker` class is not set on the input element in the second block of code.

You're also modifying the data attribute with the `data` method, but retrieving the attribute with the `attr` method. This *should* work in theory, but might be failing due to how jQuery interacts and references the DOM.

Comment: Now it looks like your `change` event in the third snippet is targeting the `.get_value` button. You'll want to target the `change` event on the `#time` input that's being updated or change the event on the button to `click`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @dzmney says

> In the last block of code you're referencing the input element by `.timepicker`, but the `timepicker` class is not set on the input element in the second block of code.

Check this and you are using the newer jQuery version.

In newer jQuery versions-

To get the contents of the attribute `data-id` (like in `<a data-id="123">link</a>`) you have to use (For newer jQuery versions (jQuery >= 1.4.3))

```
$(this).data("id")
```

For lower jQuery version jQuery (jQuery < 1.4.3) use

```
$(this).attr("data-id");
```

It is recommended to use lower case in the data key otherwise it just addresses the different attribute.

[@VisioN answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)