# get value based on id and data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a input field and a submission button like so

```html
<label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" data-belongsto="<?php echo  $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">

<button type="button" class="update_record btn btn-primary mb-3 mt-2" id="<?php $id; ?>">Update</button>
```

and i have the script like so

```js
/*Document Ready */
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.update_record', function() {
        let btnId= $(this).attr("id");
        let name = //store name value if id == "name" and data-belongsto == btnId
    });

});
```

what i want to do is to get the name value out and store it in a variable  if id == "name" and data-belongsto == btnId

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: it kinda does but is there a one liner solution to this 
like if i do the above i would need to 
compare after geting the value in if

Comment: You mean like `let name = $(this).attr('id') == 'name' && $(this).data('belongsto') == btnId ? $(this).val() : null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should avoid using "name" as id for any element because name is an attribute that is used for various [HTML input elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp#:%7E:text=The%20name%20attribute%20can%20be%20used%20on%20the%20following%20elements) which may cause issues as inputs inside a form can be addressed using their name attribute, hence I used 'nm' instead of 'name'.

And if I understood correctly, this is how you can get the desired value:

```
$(document).on('click', '.update_record', function() {
   let btnId= $(this).attr("id");

   // get the element via css selector using jquery and store its value
   let name = $(`input#nm[data-belongsto=${btnId}]`).val();
});
```