# How to change contents on clicking the selected div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, twig, chat

I am new to Javascript. I wish to change the contents of div on selecting a particular div element.
If I select a div, the text associated with that div contents only should display. I am using a loop to display the contents. It's like a chat application. If a user clicks on a contact the messages associated with that user should display. I am using a loop to display messages and users.

What I have tried is:

Twig code:

```
    {% set msg = query().from('messages').get() %}
    {% set to_add =to_name %}
{% set to_details = query().from('users_users').where('id', to_add).get() %}
    <div class="container">
               <h3 class=" text-center">Messaging</h3>
<div class="messaging">
      <div class="inbox_msg">
        <div class="inbox_people">
          <div class="headind_srch">
            <div class="recent_heading">
              <h4>{{auth_user().first_name}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="srch_bar">
              <div class="stylish-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-bar"  placeholder="Search" >
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                </span> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inbox_chat">
              {% set newArray = [] %}
              {% for msg in msg_details %}
              {% if msg.to_name not in newArray %}

             
            <div class="chat_list active_chat"  onclick=viewMessage(this)>
              <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5>{{msg.to_name}} <span class="chat_date">{{msg.time}}</span></h5>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

        </div>
        {% set newArray = newArray|merge([msg.to_name]) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mesgs">
      <div class="msg_history">
        <div class="incoming_msg">
            
          <div class="incoming_msg_img">
              <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> 
            </div>
          <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
              <p>{{msg.message}}</p>
              <span class="time_date">{{msg.time}}</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
          <div class="sent_msg">
            <p></p>
            <span class="time_date"></span> </div>
        </div>
        
       
        
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  
  

</div></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
    <script>
    function copyText(elementId){    
var x = document.getElementById(elementId).textContent;
 if(document.getElementById('select-text').value.length == 0)
         {
            document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false; 
         document.getElementById(elementId).style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
          document.getElementById('select-text').focus();
          document.getElementById('select-text').value += x;
         }
     else{
        
         document.getElementById('select-text').readOnly = true;
     }
}
</script>
```

What my output looks like

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1xPV.png)

My output shows all the messages, I want to show only the particular user message. How to do so?

What my table looks like:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhMNE.png)

Comment: when you say all the messages, do you mean the messages of the other users which does not belong to this chat?

Comment: @Dula Yes, my code shows messages of other users.

Comment: Then, you have to filter the database in your repository. Twig is just the view layer.

Comment: @Dula But I want to view the user's list and on clicking a particular user, the message of that user should display.

Comment: You can create a JSON object using twig or php and traverse it and display the messages when the name is clicked. But it is not a good solution as the JSON object size will be massive with the number of users and the messages.
The ideal way is to send an AJAX request and fetch only the selected users messages from the database.

Comment: @Dula Can you help me with the code?

Comment: I am happy to, but will need more code and data than this. If you can please update the question. I will have a look.

Comment: @Dula I have updated the code. Please look at my output and table images.

Comment: Are you using Symfony as your PHP framework?

Comment: @Dula Laravel framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to fetch the data from your table using a query something like to ensure you will get one record from each `from_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM msg GROUP BY from_id;
```

Then you can loop in twig to create the left side elements like,

```
{% for distinctMsg in distinctMsgs %}
<div class="chat_list active_chat"  data-userId="{{ distinctMsg.fromId }}">
    <div class="chat_people">
       <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
       <div class="chat_ib">
           <h5>{{distinctMsg.to_name}} <span class="chat_date">{{distinctMsg.time}}</span></h5>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in your javascript:-

```
$(".chat_list").on("click", function(){

    // have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-can-i-get-the-data-id-attribute
    var userId = $(this).data( "userId" );

    // Maybe display a loading icon in the right side div

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/msg/user/history", // your controller url
       dataType: 'json',
       headers: {
          // if you have any headers to set
          "Authorization": "Bearer {{ token }}"
       },
       data:{
          "userId" : userId
       }
    })
    .done(function (response) {
         
        // stop displaying the loading icon
        // process the response and display message history in right side
     
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
        // show proper error message
    });

});
```

**NOTE: You will have to have jQuery in your page for Ajax functions to work.**