# Get data attribute from element and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jquery code works and it is in use, but somehow my items filter not working with it correctly. But somehow my vanilla js working with that filter I use.

So my question is:

**How I can change this jquery code to vanilla js?**

```
$(".cat-name .cat-link").click(function () {

    let catID = $(this).data("id"),
        $allItem = $('.category')

    let $currentItem = $('.cat[data-category=' + catID + ']');
   
    $('.cat[data-category=' + catID + ']').addClass('active');
        $allItem.not($currentItem).removeClass('active');
    
    $('.all-items').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class from "All Items" tab
   
   });
```

Thanks if you have time to help me!

Comment: _"But somehow **my vanilla js working with that filter** I use."_ - When it already works, then what's the problem/question?

Comment: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: *"But somehow my vanilla js working with that filter I use."* I don't see any vanilla JS in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the data-id attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-can-i-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick answer :

- use `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` to select element(s)
- use `targetElement.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })` to add click event
- use `targetElement.className` to add/remove classes
- use `targetElement.getAttribute('data-...')` to manage data attributes

Remember to visit [Vanilla JS website](http://vanilla-js.com/) for more examples